# javascript edit: add fade-in feature to this script

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

currently, the image pops up, fades out, and the page pops in. however, i'd like the page to fade-in after the splash image has faded out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content {
            display:none;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#splash").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#content").show();
                });
            }, 500);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="splash">
    <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/215/482472428_5f2f592b64.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="content">
    Content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("#content").show();` to `$("#content").fadeIn("slow");`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#splash").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $("#content").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use document ready function every time I use jQuery.

BTW: You are using an out-dated jQuery, use this link instead: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content {
            display:none;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#splash").fadeOut("slow");
             $("#content").delay(500).fadeIn();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="splash">
    <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/215/482472428_5f2f592b64.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="content">
    Content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```